# oracle sql substitution variable for table prefix

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, substitution

I can't figure this out, I only want to substitute the &&QC_NUM portion, but I get prompted for a &&QC_NUM_Phase1 variable.  I thought concating the sub-var with the rest of the string would fix it, but nope.

```
DECLARE
  c INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO c
  FROM user_tables
  WHERE table_name = upper('QC_'||&&QC_NUM||'_Phase1');
  IF c             = 1 THEN
    EXECUTE immediate 'drop table QC_'||&&QC_NUM||'_Phase1';
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: What client do you use? I have just tried `select 'asd'||&&var1||'asd' from dual;` in oracle sql developer and it works as expected.

Comment: I would agree with you if I enter a number for &&var1 (it performs a implicit cast), but if I enter a string for &&var1 (e.g. I entered 'BOB'), it treats it as an identifier which is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to duplicate your error in Oracle 11g (SQL Plus or SQL Developer).
I do receive these errors with you annnoymous block:

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 8, column 7:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "BOB": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 11, column 41:
PLS-00201: identifier 'BOB' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 11, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

When I surround your substitution variable with single quotations, then the substition variable is not interpreted as an identifier, but a string.

```
DECLARE
  c INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO c
  FROM user_tables
  WHERE table_name = upper('QC_' ||'&&QC_NUM'||'_Phase1');
  IF c             = 1 THEN
    EXECUTE immediate 'drop table QC_'||'&&QC_NUM'||'_Phase1';
  END IF;
END;
```

This executes properly.